# 4-dimensional object with 5 vertices enclosing the origin

Tags: geometry

A triangle is a 2-dimensional shape with 3 vertices that may be positioned to enclose the origin.

A triangular pyramid is a 3-dimensional shape with 4 vertices that may be positioned to enclose the origin.

What convex regular shape do we get in the 4-dimensional case?

What four points $(a, b, c, d) \in \Bbb R^4$ could serve along with $(1, 0, 0, 0)$ as vertices for this shape so that its center is the origin?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex). A triangle with vertices $(1,0)$ $(0,1)$ and $(-1, -1)$ would work. A tetrahedron with $(1,0,0)$ $(0,1,0)$ $(0,0,1)$ and $(-1,-1,-1)$ would work. By extension, what coordinates could you choose in 4-space?

**Update:**

Let's construct a regular simplex with side length 1 and centroid at the origin, $O_n$. The subscript on $O$ will denote how many dimensions we are working in. We'll be a bit pedantic at the beginning, but this will prove useful when we extend into higher dimensions.

In 1 dimension, we have the points $(\pm\frac12)$, call them $A$ and $B$. Note that $AO_1:AB=1:2$.

To extend this into a triangle in 2 dimensions, let's shift these points down a bit on the $y$-axis and add a third point $C$ on the positive $y$-axis. It is a property of equilateral triangles that $AO_2:AB=2:3$, where $O_2$ is the centroid. So we need to shift our existing points (including $O_1$) down $\frac13$ the height of the triangle, and add our third point $\frac23$ the height of the triangle up the $y$-axis.

To find the height of the triangle, we look at right triangle $AO_1C$, and by Pythagoras, $O_1C=\sqrt{1^2-(\frac12)^2}=\frac{\sqrt3}2$. Dividing this by 3 gives $\frac{\sqrt3}6=\frac1{2\sqrt3}$, and multiplying by 2 gives $\frac{\sqrt3}3=\frac1{\sqrt3}$. So our triangle $ABC$ has the points $(\pm\frac12,-\frac1{2\sqrt3})$, $(0,\frac1{\sqrt3})$.

Continuing, we find the height of the corresponding tetrahedron by using right triangle $AO_2D$. $O_2D=\sqrt{1-(\frac1{\sqrt3})^2}=\sqrt\frac23$. We will have $AO_3:AD=3:4$, so we shift our triangle down on the $z$-axis by $\frac{\sqrt\frac23}4=\frac1{2\sqrt6}$, and add the new point $D$ at $\frac3{2\sqrt6}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}$ on the $z$-axis. The points are now $(\pm\frac12,-\frac1{2\sqrt3},-\frac1{2\sqrt6})$, $(0, \frac1{\sqrt3},-\frac1{2\sqrt6})$, $(0,0,\frac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2})$.

The same pattern extends into 4 dimensions. We find the height of the 4-simplex by using right triangle $AO_3E$. The same technique gives $O_3E=\sqrt{1-(\frac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2})^2}=\sqrt\frac58$. We will have $AO_4:AB=4:5$. We shift the tetrahedron down on the $4^{th}$ axis by $\frac{\sqrt\frac58}5=\frac1{\sqrt{40}}=\frac1{2\sqrt{10}}$, and add the new point $E$ at $\frac4{2\sqrt{10}}=\sqrt\frac25$.

This gives our 5 points as:

$$(\pm\frac12,-\frac1{2\sqrt3},-\frac1{2\sqrt6},-\frac1{2\sqrt{10}})$$ $$(\hspace{8pt}0\hspace{8pt},\hspace{8pt}\frac1{\sqrt3}\hspace{6pt},-\frac1{2\sqrt6},-\frac1{2\sqrt{10}})$$ $$(\hspace{8pt}0\hspace{8pt},\hspace{13pt}0\hspace{14pt},\hspace{5pt}\frac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}\hspace{5pt},-\frac1{2\sqrt{10}})$$ $$(\hspace{8pt}0\hspace{8pt},\hspace{13pt}0\hspace{14pt},\hspace{14pt}0\hspace{14pt},\hspace{9pt}\sqrt\frac25\hspace{9pt})$$

This is with fully reduced fractions everywhere, and we see patterns everywhere except on the diagonal. However, if we rationalize the denominators on the diagonal...

$$(\pm\frac12,-\frac1{2\sqrt3},-\frac1{2\sqrt6},-\frac1{2\sqrt{10}})$$ $$(\hspace{8pt}0\hspace{8pt},\hspace{8pt}\frac{\sqrt3}3\hspace{6pt},-\frac1{2\sqrt6},-\frac1{2\sqrt{10}})$$ $$(\hspace{8pt}0\hspace{8pt},\hspace{13pt}0\hspace{14pt},\hspace{7pt}\frac{\sqrt6}4\hspace{7pt},-\frac1{2\sqrt{10}})$$ $$(\hspace{8pt}0\hspace{8pt},\hspace{13pt}0\hspace{14pt},\hspace{14pt}0\hspace{14pt},\hspace{7pt}\frac{\sqrt{10}}5\hspace{8pt})$$

Triangular numbers everywhere! In 5 dimensions, the $5^{th}$ coordinate for these points will be $-\frac1{2\sqrt{15}}$, and point $F$ will be at $(0,0,0,0,\frac{\sqrt{15}}6)$. Note also how $\pm\frac12$ fits both patterns.

Comment: Thanks, I see the pattern.  Do you know how to construct a regular shape satisfying these properties?

Comment: That is trickier, but let's try it the same way. Can you do it for the triangle case?

Comment: Yes.  Consider $\Bbb C = \Bbb R^2$ and take the third roots of unity.

Comment: Sure, can you extend it to a tetrahedron?

Comment: You can see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn) to get the vertices of a regular simplex.  Now if you average all the corners you find a point within it, so translate that to the origin

Comment: Come on Ross, let him solve it, he's close.

Comment: I had a peek at the answer Ross gave.  That's what I was looking for!  Thank you both.

Comment: You will learn more and get more enjoyment out of it if you try to derive an answer on your own, by figuring the tetrahedron case and extending it. Hint: the ratio of the height of a regular triangle to the distance from a vertex to its centroid is 3:2.

Comment: @Zook:  Sorry, I hadn't seen you were working on that.  It isn't so obvious to me how to easily get a regular one in higher dimensions.  I wanted to put the $n$ simplex into the all positive corner of $n+1$ space, but that becomes a mess quickly.

Comment: All good, if he actually cares about it he will continue to try. I would drop the triangle he just constructed down a bit on the $z$-axis and stick another point on the positive $z$-axis, knowing that the same ratio given in my last comment is 4:3 for the tetrahedron case, and scale accordingly.

Comment: I'll try and figure it out intuitively using your method, Zook, and if that fails, I'll use the formulaic method provided by Ross.

Comment: Roots of unity are a good start, however I would scale it so your side length is 1, that way you don't have to keep changing coordinates in higher dimensions. You'll want to use Pythagoras to find the heights

Comment: Alright so I've just solved this, and there is a really cool pattern in the coordinates. How's it coming on your end?

Comment: I have an answer.  It involves a lot of square roots and it'll take a while to type out in TeX.

Comment: Check out my update :)

Comment: Very nice @Zook!

Answer (score 2):

$$\left({1, 0, 0, 0}\right)$$
$$\left( {-\frac{1}{4}, \sqrt{\frac{15}{16}}, 0, 0} \right)$$
$$\left({-\frac{1}{4}, -\sqrt{\frac{5}{48}}, \sqrt{\frac{5}{6}}, 0}\right)$$ 
$$\left({-\frac{1}{4}, -\sqrt{\frac{5}{48}}, -\sqrt{\frac{5}{24}},-\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}}\right)$$
$$\left({-\frac{1}{4}, -\sqrt{\frac{5}{48}}, -\sqrt{\frac{5}{24}},\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}}}\right)$$

Comment: That's good, Wolfram alpha confirms the distance between all points is $\sqrt\frac52$. I'll write mine up tomorrow and show you the pattern I found.